how to add a new column that contain the current date?
Using AWS EMR 7.2 and Spark-SQL and Hudi
spark-sql --jars /usr/lib/hudi/hudi-spark-bundle.jar,/usr/lib/hudi/hudi-aws-bundle.jar --conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog" --conf "spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension" 

The normal add a date column would be this
alter table account add columns (date date);

how do you add it with curdate()?

Are you trying to add a column to a dataframe, a databricks table, a view on a dataframe,...?

ALTER TABLE account
MODIFY COLUMN date DATE DEFAULT CURDATE();

spark-sql (default)> ALTER TABLE account MODIFY COLUMN date DATE DEFAULT CURDATE();
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'MODIFY'.(line 1, pos 20)
== SQL == ALTER TABLE account MODIFY COLUMN date DATE DEFAULT CURDATE() --------------------^^^ 

If you change it to ALTER TABLE account ADD COLUMN date DATE DEFAULT CURDATE();, it adds the coumn but it shows NULLs in the field
